# Google Sheet App Script not working on mobile devices

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, shopify

Actually I have a form in Shopify, so when user submit the form, all the entries should be saved on the google sheet and it's working perfectly from desktop. But when I submit the form using mobile devices then form is submit succesfully but it does not save data in Shopify.

Can anybody guide me what exactly I have to do on the mobile device. I think I might need to get some sort of setting in google sheet to access it but I didn't get it yet.

I am using this scripts to save data to google sheet. https://github.com/waqarulhassan89/Save-Shopify-Contact-Form-in-Google-Sheets/blob/master/google_scripts.gs

Can anybody guide me what exactly I have to do on the mobile device. I think I might need to get some sort of setting in google sheet to access it but I didn't get it yet.

Comment: I think you need to ask the developer of the script, I have checked the configuration video added to YouTube and that video has the same missing issue. so the developer can say anything about it.

Comment: @Onkar I have checked with android users and it's working perfectly. It's only not working with iPhone users. do you know anything, is their any permission issue for google sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be coming from the `getActiveSpreadsheet` you put in your `setup()` function. Chances are you have the spreadsheet open and it's running off of that. Your users (probably) won't have the sheet open, so you should call the sheet by either `openByUrl()` or `openById()`

```js
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

//  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    
    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(your URL here); //replaces getActiveSpreadsheet()
    // var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(your ID here); (optional)
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for reply to my question,

I have changed the setup function with your function. But it still does not work for mobile users.

Sometimes it saves the entries from mobile devices. I think there is something else issue